# Async error "Current thread must have a looper" when clicking retry button

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app that reads some data from a website and then creates `TextViews` for what is retrieved from the website. I have the process working through an `AsyncTask`. I've got it set up so that if there is a network error while trying to read from the website, a Retry button is shown. My code works perfect when it runs through the first time, but when I try to run the code from the `onClick` of the button, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    (a few lines of error code)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!
```

I even tried to have the `onClick` call an outside method as I saw someone recommend, but that didn't help. Here is some of the relevant code:

**Async Task**

```
private class DownloadListingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        showLoadingPage();
        try{
            return getList(urls[0]);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            return sharedPreferences.getString("list_cache", "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        formatList(result);
    }
}
```

**Calling method**

```
private void tryDownload(){
    DownloadListingTask downloadListingTask = new DownloadListingTask();
    downloadListingTask.execute(url);
}
```

**onClick event**

```
retryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tryDownload();
            }
        });
```

So when the `tryDownload()` method is called from `onCreateView` it works fine, but when I try it from the `onClick` is when I get that error.

Comment: What is the code running in the beginning of the doInBackground method showLoadingPage()? It seems like you're trying to make UI manipulations in an Async Task, instead of wating to achieve the mutation in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call showLoadingPage in onPreExecute method:

```
private class DownloadListingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
          showLoadingPage();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        try{
            return getList(urls[0]);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            return sharedPreferences.getString("list_cache", "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        formatList(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that! It's weird that it still worked the first time this task was ran, just not when I used the retry button. Not really sure why I'm getting down votes on my question, but thank you for the answer. That was it!

Comment: @DuckyDisciple I have the similar problem in the past. When views are created - only main thread can change it contents (sometimes people calls it UI Thread). onPreExecute method is called on ui thread and views can be updated. But doInBackground is not calling on ui thread and you have getting the exception if views are created and rendered. Always update ui in ui thread.

Answer (score 7):

This code worked for me:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        primaryProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for answers and are using RxJava for async operations, this might be helpful.

When using Rxjava if you don't specify the *observing* thread then this error will come.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!

so don't forget to add

> subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
>
> observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //required

```
 disposableObserver = Observable.timer(2000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    //some code
                }
            });
```

Comment: Also make sure you specify the non IO/Computation operations that is the UI operations after the `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` like so: 
`.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .doOnSubscribe(...)
  .doOnComplete(...)
   .subscribe(...)`